# Ionic Angular HttpClient injection not working

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ionic5, nswagstudio

I have auto-generated a WebAPI service module with NSwagStudio to connect my Ionic/Angular app and my webservice together. This service (WebApiConnector.Client) is configured to be injected:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [    
    GooglePlus,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: WebApiConnector.API_BASE_URL, useValue: environment.apiURL },
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true },
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler},
    AuthService,
    WebApiConnector.Client

  ],
```

When I run the app on browser or debug it on android device, all works like a charm, but when I build it in production with:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

the HttpClient injected into WebAPI service seems to be undefined because when the first call is performed, the app falls into this exception:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of
>   undefined

The call is performed inside ngAfterViewInit() hook.

I also tried to inject HttpClient into the page where "WebApiConnector.Client" is injected to perform manually the request to the server, but it perfectly worked.

This is the service module configuration

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBase } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Client {
    private http: HttpClient;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "/webapi_2";
    }
```

and this is the snippet of code that throw the exception:

```
return this.http.request("get", url_, options_)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is for that particular line?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, because I've put a chek before that line, if (typeof this.http == 'undefined') { alert('http is undefined'); } and when I run it, the alert is displayed before the exception.

Comment: Are the providers above the ones from AppModule? Can you try removing the Client from the providers array? And in which module is the page using the client?

Comment: What do you mean with "Are the providers above the ones from AppModule?"? If I remove Client from providers array I receive "NullInjectorError". I think that the page using the client has no module, or I guess so, I'm not a master of Angular, sorry.

Comment: I tried to remove the module WebApiConnector where the Client class is encapsulated and wIthout it, the injection of httpclient works. I tried to search some info about this problem without results. Do you have some advices?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know